# CSS error tool tips not working properly

Tags: html, css

I got my general CSS code for the tool tips from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_left), but tried tailoring it to my needs:

```
/* The tooltip stuff */
.tooltip
{
    top: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #e55;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}


.tooltip::after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #e55 transparent transparent;
}
```

For some reason, however, when I test this with a dummy tool tip, it not only is missing its arrow, but it isn't even on the row that needs it! Even worse, the tool tips, for some reason, sit on top each other!

[image]

The HTML code to the main div is as follows:

```
<div class="main pageCenter">
    <form id="newUserRegistration">
        <span class="row">
            <label for="firstName" class="half">First name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" class="half">
                <span class="tooltip">text</span>                   
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="lastName" class="half">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" class="half">
                <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>                    
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="empIDNumber" class="half">Employee ID number</label>
            <input type="text" class="number" class="half">
                <span class="tooltip">other text</span>     
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="dept" class="half">Department</label>
            <select id="dept" class="half">
            <!-- To be populated with data from a Mustache template-->
            {{#departments}}
                <option id="{{departmentHTMLID}}">{{departmentName}}</option>
            {{/departments}}
            </select>
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>        
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="manager" class="half">Manager name</label>
            <input type="text" id="manager" class="half">
                <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>    
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="username" class="half">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="half">
                <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>    
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="password" class="half">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" class="half">
                <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>    
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class="half">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="text" id="confirmPassword" class="half">
                <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="email" class="half" title="A confirmation email will be sent to this e-mail address.">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="email" class="half" title="A confirmation email will be sent to this e-mail address.">
                <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>
            </input>
        </span>
        <span class="right row buttonRow">
            <input type="reset" class="right" value="Clear"/>
            <input type="submit" class="right" value="Submit" />
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the rest of my CSS code is as follows:

```
/* Fractional-width classes */
.fiveSixths { width: 83.3333333333333333%; }
.fourFifths { width: 80%; }
.threeFourths { width: 75%; }
.twoThirds { width: 66.6666666666666667%; }
.threeFifths { width: 60%; }
.half { width: 50%; }
.twoFifths { width: 40%; }
.third { width: 33.3333333333333333%; }
.fourth { width: 25%;}
.fifth { width: 20%; }
.sixth { width: 16.6666666666666667%; }

.main
{
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px orange;
}

.main > *
{
    padding: 10px;
}

.pageCenter
 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text"],input[type="password"], input[type="email"]
{
    border-left-style: none !important;
    border-right-style: none !important;
    border-top-style: none !important;
    border-bottom-color: #888 !important;
}


input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"],button
{
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="submit"]
{
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: orange;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    background-color: #fb0;
}

.hidden
{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.row:not(.buttonRow),.rowTight:not(.buttonRow)
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.row
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rowTight
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.right
{
    float: right;
}

.number
{
    text-align: right;
}

.main
{
    min-width: 450px;
    width: 50%;
}

#formContainer
{
    padding: 20px;
}

#newUserRegistration > *:not(input[type="submit"])
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#newUserRegistration > * > *
{
    float: left;
}

#newUserRegistration > * > *:not(:first-child):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):not(button)
{
    margin-left: -4px;  
}

#newUserRegistration span
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I've been trying to play with this for a while, but couldn't get the tool tips to position properly, nor for them to not be on top each other.

Comment: What did you expect? You are using `position: absolute`...

Comment: Check linked example again - scheme is: tooltip 'container' is positioned relative, tooltip it self - absolute. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Declare `relative` positioning on the tooltip containing elements, `.rowTight`

Comment: Two downvotes and a vote to close? Explain how this question warranted that.

Comment: declaring `relative` did nothing: https://imgur.com/a/FXBiY

Comment: Just to clarify, have you declared `position: relative` to `.rowTight`, while retaining `absolute` positioning on tooltips? That image looks like you've declared `relative` positioning on the tooltips.

Comment: It seems when I hard-code that into the file (versus just playing with it in the browser), I get another bizarre result. https://imgur.com/a/JLxf8

Could we move this to a JSFiddle? This is becoming ridiculous.

Comment: The code you've provided cannot reproduce a working example to troubleshoot; there's no indication in the styles of how these *tooltips* should appear, they will always remain hidden because of the class `.hidden` added to them. The tooltips are also empty and contain no text so would not be visible even if the CSS code required to have them display were present. I see there is invalid markup you have as well, `input` elements are *self-closing void elements*, which means they **cannot contain any other elements**.

Comment: Just set-up a working example I can troubleshoot and demonstrate a solution with.

Comment: The first and third `.tooltip`s were not `.hidden`. I fixed the markup problem and the original problem is there. I'm going to attempt dropping this code into a JSFiddle.

Comment: Let me know with a mention (@UncaughtTypeError) once you have a working reproduction set up that I can take a look at.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError https://jsfiddle.net/d9n5w3La/1/

Comment: @MikeWarren https://jsfiddle.net/d9n5w3La/2/

Comment: @MikeWarren If this worked for you, let me know so that I can add it as answer officially and go into a little more detail on the solutions employed.

Comment: It did, but it caused some issues elsewhere, namely with the positioning of the buttons and that the number field not being where it was, and the buttons' order is reversed

Comment: The order of the buttons can be easily addressed just by switching around their placements in the html, the number field had two separate class attributes, one of these (`.half`) was being omitted by the browser after parsing, combining the attribute values resolves this. Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9n5w3La/3/ (remember to use mentions so that I receive notifications of your responses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `position: relative` was declared on your containing elements, the `overflow: auto` property declared in addition prevented any overflow of the element's contents being visible, and so the tooltip could not be properly observed because of this.

**To address this:**

1. Remove the `float: left` rules declared on nested elements by the
   following rule: `#newUserRegistration > * > *` - the global
   selectors (`*`) for this rule causes havoc in this case, and should
   be avoided, for better practice use more *specific* selectors and
   only style what you are required to.
2. Only float your *form fields* `right`, with more specific selectors,
   e.g:

   ```
   #newUserRegistration select, #newUserRegistration input {
       float: right;
   }
   ```
3. You are no longer required to clear floats using `overflow: auto` on
   the containing parent element, allowing your absolutely positioned
   tooltips to remain visible. In addition, a `left` positioning property has been added to your tooltips.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9n5w3La/3/)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
/* The tooltip stuff */
.tooltip
{
    top: -5px;
    left: 100%; /* Added - position absolute tooltip relative to parent row */
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #e55;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}


.tooltip::after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #e55 transparent transparent;
}

/* Fractional-width classes */
.fiveSixths { width: 83.3333333333333333%; }
.fourFifths { width: 80%; }
.threeFourths { width: 75%; }
.twoThirds { width: 66.6666666666666667%; }
.threeFifths { width: 60%; }
.half { width: 50%; }
.twoFifths { width: 40%; }
.third { width: 33.3333333333333333%; }
.fourth { width: 25%;}
.fifth { width: 20%; }
.sixth { width: 16.6666666666666667%; }

.main
{
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px orange;
}

.main > *
{
    padding: 10px;
}

.pageCenter
 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="text"],input[type="password"], input[type="email"]
{
    border-left-style: none !important;
    border-right-style: none !important;
    border-top-style: none !important;
    border-bottom-color: #888 !important;
}


input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"],button
{
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="submit"]
{
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: orange;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    background-color: #fb0;
}

.hidden
{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.row:not(.buttonRow),.rowTight:not(.buttonRow)
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.row
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rowTight
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.right
{
    float: right;
}

.number
{
    text-align: right;
}

.main
{
    min-width: 450px;
    width: 50%;
}

#formContainer
{
    padding: 20px;
}

#newUserRegistration > *:not(input[type="submit"])
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#newUserRegistration > * > * /* this is causing mayhem, selectors should be more specific */
{
    float: left;
}

/* ...like this */
#newUserRegistration select, #newUserRegistration input {
    float: right;
}
#newUserRegistration label {
    float: none;
}

#newUserRegistration > * > *:not(:first-child):not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):not(button)
{
    margin-left: -4px;  
}

/* not necessary, since you no longer need to clear nested elements that are floated
#newUserRegistration span
{
    overflow: auto;
} */
```

```html
<div class="main pageCenter">
    <form id="newUserRegistration">
        <span class="row">
            <label for="firstName" class="half">First name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" class="half" />
            <span class="tooltip">text</span>                   
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="lastName" class="half">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" class="half" />
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>                    
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="empIDNumber" class="half">Employee ID number</label>
            <input type="text" class="number half" />
            <span class="tooltip">other text</span>     
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="dept" class="half">Department</label>
            <select id="dept" class="half">
            <!-- To be populated with data from a Mustache template-->
            {{#departments}}
                <option id="{{departmentHTMLID}}">{{departmentName}}</option>
            {{/departments}}
            </select>
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>        
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="manager" class="half">Manager name</label>
            <input type="text" id="manager" class="half" />
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>    
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="username" class="half">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="half" />
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>    
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="password" class="half">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" class="half" />
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>    
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class="half">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="text" id="confirmPassword" class="half" />
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>
            
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
            <label for="email" class="half" title="A confirmation email will be sent to this e-mail address.">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="email" class="half" title="A confirmation email will be sent to this e-mail address." />
            <span class="hidden tooltip"></span>
            
        </span>
        <span class="right row buttonRow">
            <input type="submit" class="right" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" class="right" value="Clear"/>
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this! btw, after inspecting it a little, I found a way to not have to re-arrange the HTML buttons: 
I added `:not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"]):not(button)` to the end of that input `float : right; ` rule

Comment: That is super-specific - but it'll work :) Glad you came right in the end.